# Spring Boot OAuth2 + Cognito Integration login + Throw 401 error

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-cognito, spring-oauth2

I use Spring Boor OAuth2 with Cognito for the authentication of my app.
My config :
application.yml :

```
 spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
# Security config for authentication provider in the Web Application
        registration:
          cognito:
            client-id: 4444444444kq1s7q87gs5
            client-secret: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            client-name: client-test
            provider: cognito
            scope: openid
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/cognito
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
```

In AWS Console :
[image]

When I run my app : http://localhost:8080, I got the default login page of cognito :
[image]

But I got this error when I put my credentials :

[image]

Someone can help ? What wrong ?

Comment: you need to make your login API public (non-authenticated)

Comment: And how can I do it ?

Comment: added ans, try that

Comment: your issue got resolved??

Comment: Not yet, do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a security configuration class and add /login API in ignore list

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BasicConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/login");
    }
    
}
```

Change name of your login API

Comment: Thx .. I added this `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/login/**");` but I got 404 error

Comment: Cross check your controller, have you created any api with path: /login/oauth2/code/cognito

Comment: Yes I did it, in my controller I have 2 api : @GetMapping(value = "/") => return "redirect:/index.html"; and @GetMapping(value = "/login/oauth2/code/cognito") and for this if i return also the index.html I got error .. I have only one HTML file in my folder (I use angular so when I build my app I have only index.html)

Comment: @user1814879, please approve answer if this helps..

Comment: Yes no worry I will .. but for the moment I got error when I add the api /login/oauth2 .. because I have not html page to return .. I have only one HTML Page in my folder and it is index.html (I use angular )